# understanding out.println in servlets

Tags: java, servlets, console, println

How in Servlets, `out.println` writes the html text to container's response object where normally in `System.out.println()` , it writes the text to the console??

This is creating a problem for me conceptually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `PrintStream` nor `PrintWriter` is specified in terms of a console.

A PrintStream adds functionality to another output stream, namely the ability to print representations of various data values conveniently. [PrintStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html)

Prints formatted representations of objects to a text-output stream. [PrintWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html)

They are both about formatting data and passing the formatted data to an output stream. Any output stream. By default, in certain environments, the `PrintStream` objects initially referenced by each of `System.out` and `System.err` send their data to some sort of console, but that is just those particular instances.

Even those can be changed. For example, it can be useful in some types of testing to replace `System.out` with a `PrintStream` that sends its data to a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: So to which outputstream class does the printstream forward the formatted data in case of system.out to print to the console like it does to ServletOutputStream in servlets?

Comment: @awhitesong Each `PrintStream` gets told about its output stream as a constructor parameter. See the documentation I referenced above.

Answer (score 2):

It uses a [`ServletOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletOutputStream.html) from the Javadoc,

> Provides an output stream for sending binary data to the client. A `ServletOutputStream` object is normally retrieved via the [`ServletResponse.getOutputStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream()) method.

If you look at [`System.out`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out) you can see that it's a [`PrintStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) which is a different implementation of [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html).

Comment: isn't out in servlets a reference to PrintWriter class which we get through PrintWriter out=response.getwriter() declaration in servlets code ?

Comment: @awhitesong It depends entirely on the underlying `OutputStream` that the `PrintWriter` prints to. In the case of the `Servlet`, that prints to the `OutputStream` I linked to in my answer. Also, `System.out` is not a `PrintWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

If someplace in a servlet an invocation of `out.println(...)` writes to the response object, then `out` must be a reference to the response object's `OutputStream`, or a wrapper stream and it.  If `System.out` sends output someplace else (as normally it would do) then it is a reference to a different `OutputStream`.

A servlet method's (or any other method's) local variable named `out` is completely unrelated to `System.out`, barring you initializing the one as a reference to the other.

Comment: The out in servlets has a reference to PrintWriter class and PrintWriter's or PrintStream's println() generally writes to the console right?

Comment: **There is no general "out in servlets".**  If unqualified `out` is meaningful in some method of some servlet, then it is probably local variable, though it could also be an instance or class variable of the particular servlet implementation class.  Such a variable refers to whatever object, if any, it was last set to refer to.  In a servlet of mine, it would probably be initialized to refer to the output stream of the current `ServletResponse` object.